# Mysql: is mysql_setpermission deprecated?

Tags: mysql

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit repo, and installed mysql-server via apt-get. I noticed that mysql_setpermission is not installed on my server. Has it been deprecated, or is it part of another package?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of MySQL did you install? According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-setpermission.html, that script is indeed deprecated since v5.6.17 and was removed in v5.7

Comment: Thanks, so I assume there is no substitute script for MySQL available then, and all permissions etc needs to be done directly on mysql command line then? Or, as per comments below, I need to move to MariaDB?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_setpermission is in mariadb-server package which is the fork of mysql.

Comment: Can you explain that further? According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-setpermission.html, that is part of MySQL too

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=cosmic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=mysql_setpermission
<pre>
File Packages
/usr/bin/mysql_setpermission mariadb-server-10.1
/usr/share/man/man1/mysql_setpermission.1.gz mariadb-server-10.1
</pre>

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer, not to the comment section. And please use an **explanation** and not just a raw dump of data

Comment: I cannot explain it because I'm not a package designer in Ubuntu, sorry.
Ask Ubuntu for expanations... :(

Comment: You could start explaining what you mean by that comment, and you should add that explanation to your answer, not to the comment secion

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu package browser shows the following:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=cosmic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=mysql_setpermission

[image: Ubuntu package browser screenshot]

Comment: This answer might benefit from a little more explanation - what are we supposed to be looking for? :)